# How to display formatted code in webpage

Tags: c#, html, css

I am trying to write a blog and I want to display c# code in a neat formatted way. Is there a way to it. I like to do it exactly the way stack overflow does including color. :)

Comment: May I suggest [Github Gists](https://gist.github.com/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have *quite a few options* here, but I would recommend against using a JavaScript formatter.  If a user has scripts disabled, you still want the code to look good.

**If you are using Visual Studio, the Productivity Power Tools add-in has a "copy HTML" option:**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/06/07/copy-code-in-html-format-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

**Jon Skeet provides a code formatter for public use:**
http://csharpindepth.com/CodeFormatterTool.aspx

**If you are using PHP, GeSHi is a good server-side option:**
http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

**I believe that stack-overflow uses google-code-prettify:**
http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

**SyntaxHighlighter is another good client-side solution:**
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: Thank you John. Posting code on my blog is a breeze. I am using visual studio 2010 and Productivity Power Tool is quick.

Comment: Is there any part of the internet that still looks good with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Anything I build looks good without it.  I am a big fan of "progressive enhancement."

Comment: @JohnGietzen Three Years later and your comment is still awkward

Comment: The Jon Skeet one is no longer available :(

Answer (score 9):

SO uses [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which is Javascript + CSS. You should get all the documentation you need on that site.

Also, if you don't mind using PHP, there's [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/). But client-side is probably better, so I'd go with the code prettifier.

Comment: +1 #wow .. i didn't noticed it was prettify that was used by SO

Comment: Thank you Rafe. For now I started using visual studio addin. I will definitely look into prettify today.

Comment: Please let me know how to make scrolling vertically or horizontally by using google-code-prettify at blogspot.com

Answer (score 4):

you can use third-party if you want: [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter)

Comment: Thanks. When fully set up, this one looks best and has the most features.

Answer (score 3):

The **Syntax Highlighter** and  **google-code-prettify** are the client-side solutions, its probably better because its more versatile to be applied in any web pages ( *.php* | *.aspx* | *.jsp* | *.html* ). Its downfall is that :

1. Initially when the page is loaded, formatted code is displayed in raw format. It takes up some time for the javascript to build the syntax highlighting of the code.
2. Doesn't work if the javascript is disabled.

**Solution**: Pre-build the syntax formatted code. [Syntax Highlight Generator](http://ajblk.github.io/SyntaxHighlightGenerator-v3.0/OnlineGenerator.html) is an open source Online Tool to pre-build your code. This tool is built over Syntax Highlighter v3.0 library.

**Syntax Highlight Generator's configuration:**
[codeworkout.blogspot.com/2014/07/online-generator-tool-for-code-syntax_18.html](http://codeworkout.blogspot.com/2014/07/online-generator-tool-for-code-syntax_18.html)

Answer (score -5):

```
    <blockquote>
             //.....Code
    <blockquote>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Try to add some more detail so that it is more complete.