# how do i display c# source code on a web page

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display formatted code in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170055/how-to-display-formatted-code-in-webpage)

I'm sure this question must have been asked before however I cannot find it anywhere.
(I must be searching for the wrong thing)

Much like this site allows you to do, I would like to place c# onto my webpage so that I can write tutorials / examples.

```
var tute = new Tutorial();    
//Display all of this 
SomeMethod(tute);
```

is this performed by `CSS` trickery? and if so is there a library that can be taken to do this?

Comment: http://pygments.org/ could be useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625818/rich-text-editor-on-a-web-page

Comment: http://colorcode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's all done via CSS. Here is a [blog post](http://www.pvladov.com/2012/10/colorize-csharp-code-for-blog.html) that should help you.

Comment: Its not all done with just CSS. You have to wrap the code segment with the proper HTML (`<code></code>`) tags as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a html tag named [Code](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp) , You can use it and CSS to create yours code block.

for example :

```
<html>
<style>
code
{
   background-color : gray;
   padding : 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<code>Your code here</code>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have code render on an HTML page you need to wrap it in a `<code>` tag.

The better approach is to combine it with a `<pre>` tag as well so that you indentation and spacing formatting is retained as well.

```
<pre>
<code>
    Your code here
</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of projects that will do this. One that I know of is on CodePlex called "ColorCode" which can color your code (by formatting it as HTML). You can append the output to a document:

http://colorcode.codeplex.com/